# Does Monero network difficulty affect the amount of XMR I get from a pool?

Tags: monero-network-hashrate, difficulty, monero-mining

**Does Monero network difficulty affect the amount of XMR I get from a pool?**

I used a calculation from one of the previous questions:

```
((your hashrate) / (the network hashrate)) * (720 blocks per day) * (block reward) = XMR/day
```

Now I'm interested in the importance of network difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficulty is the same as network hash rate, but expressed differently.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Monero network difficulty affect the amount of XMR I get from a pool?

If your hashrate stays static whilst the network difficulty goes up, your expected earnings will go down.

> Now I'm interested in the importance of network difficulty.

See @user36303's [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12383/7493). Difficulty and hashrate refer to the same thing just expressed differently.